# Simmer add_dataframe with col_attributes error

Tags: r, simulation

Using simmer I get an error when I use add_dataframe with an attribute column:

```
library(simmer)

workerCount <- 2

actualData <- data.frame(
  time = c(1:10,1:5), priority = 1:3, service = rnorm(15, 50, 5)) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(time)

actualData$gender<-floor(runif(15, min=1, max=3))

activityTraj <- trajectory() %>%
  seize('worker') %>%
  timeout_from_attribute("service") %>%
  release('worker')

env <- simmer() %>%
  add_resource('worker', workerCount, Inf, preemptive = TRUE) %>%
  add_dataframe('worker_', activityTraj, actualData, mon=2, col_time="time", time="absolute", col_attributes=c("gender")) %>%
  run()
```

The error I get is:

```
Error: 'worker_0' at 1.00 in [Seize]->Timeout->[Release]:
 missing value (NA or NaN returned)
```

I'm using simmer_4.3.0

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifying just `col_attributes=c("gender")`, and therefore the `service` column is ignored.